# Generic code to fade in divs with particular class, remove function after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a generic function that can be placed just once in my site and work across multiple pages, nice and lightweight.

I want to be able to make certain divs on the site fade-in when you reach 10px above them on the scroll.

I want to do this by simply adding the following attributes to my divs:

`.fade-in-block`
`#specific-block-name`

The idea is that I could go through the site, add this class and an ID, and the animation would work.

I almost have it working except for one thing, **the scroll listening constantly continues to `console.log` after the function has been called**. I don't like this as it feels like it's going to be constantly trying to apply the animation, which won't really be seen from the front-end but I feel the constant maths behind the scenes could slow stuff down.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('body .fade-in-block').each(function(){
            var block = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
            console.log('Block class is = '+block);
            var offset = $(block).offset().top;
            var $w = $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($w.scrollTop() > offset - 10) {
                    console.log('reached block turn-on point for '+block);
                    $(block).removeAttr('id'); // remove the ID from the element so the script doesn't continue to find the element
                    // fade and rise animation here
                }
            });
        });
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c8zam17/1/). It works just fine, but once you hit the block you'll see it logs *constantly* every pixel scrolled.

I tried to remedy this by removing the selecting `id` from the element once the event has occurred, but it continues to run.

Comment: Use `$(window).unbind('scroll');` after the line `$(block).removeAttr...`

Comment: @Ananth this then only enact the JS for the first element on the page with that class. I do want it to continue for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll and resize events both have this problem and the solution is said to be [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).  However, I've never actually gotten debouncing to work properly.  Instead I typically create a sort of switch that is turned off once the scroll condition has activated.  In your case, since you have multiple elements, you would need to assign a switch to each element.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('.fade-in-block').each(function(){
        var appear = $(this).attr('data-appeared');
        if(!appear){
            $(this).attr('data-appeared', true);
            //do something to $(this)
        }
    })
})
```

Here I'm adding a data attribute after it has appeared and checking for it again once it has.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good solution. Similar to what I was doing, but I was trying to remove the class to determine the fade whereas you have added a new one. I got it working and have updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9c8zam17/4/